# Double integral over the set with an absolute value of $y$

Tags: calculus, integration, absolute-value

I need to calculate an integral over the set:

$$D \colon 0\leq x\leq \pi\text{ and }|y|\leq x$$

from the set (definite integral) $D \int \cos(y)dA$

I don't understand what $|y| \leq x$ means. 
Can someone give me a tip how to calculate this?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE, asfdnad: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/).  It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Answer (score 2):

$|y| \leq x$ means $-x \leq y \leq x$, so those are your limits for $y$.

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{-x}^{x} \cos(y) dy dx$$